# Arrayformula with networkdays in gSheet - it does not work

Tags: arrays, date, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to change a normal formula to ARRAYFORMULA() and I have an issue.

This is normal formula:

```
=IF(E3="","",(NETWORKDAYS(D3,E3,$F$3:$F)-1)($K$4-$K$3)+IF(NETWORKDAYS(E3,E3),MEDIAN(MOD(E3,1),$K$4,$K$3),$K$4)-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS(D3,D3)*MOD(D3,1),$K$4,$K$3))
```

Legend: 
D3 - start date 
E3 - end date 
F3:F - Holidays 
K3 - start hour 
K4 - end hour

I set: 
 
D3 - start date 2020-07-12 15:00 
E3 - end date 2020-07-13 12:00 
F3:F - Holidays 2020-07-01 
K3 - start hour 8:00 
K4 - end hour 17:30 
 
The result should be 4:00 (hours) because start date is on Sunday (so without this day).

And this is my ARRAYFORMULA:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E3:E="","",(NETWORKDAYS(D3:D,E3:E,$F$3:$F)-1)*($K$4-$K$3)+IF(NETWORKDAYS(E3:E,E3:E),MEDIAN(MOD(E3:E,1),$K$4,$K$3),$K$4)-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS(D3:D,D3:D)*MOD(D3:D,1),$K$4,$K$3)))
```

Any ideas? :)

UPDATE: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cj_6gluz5xdRG7ZbQiy6nLNIAqdwWszmSCzL6JuU-AM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Adam, can you please share a sample sheet, with your data and formulas, so we can work on this?

Comment: Can you explain in words what this part of the formula is doing? `IF(NETWORKDAYS(G3:G,G3:G),MEDIAN(MOD(G3:G,1),$O$4,$O$3),$O$4)`    Won't `NETWORKDAYS(G3:G,G3:G)` always return a value of 1?

Comment: I added a link to sheet. This formula is check if date from G is workday (without Holidays and weekends), and if it is, it will a time from field.  So when you set in G3 for example 2020-07-18 (Saturday), the result will be 0.

Comment: Your sheet seems a bit confused - you have no values in column F, where your formula implies a range of dates in both F and G.  What are column B, Answer Date, and column E. Correct Result?  Should the results of the formula you want match one of those? Do you want the arrayformula in column I?  And your question says holidays are in H3:H, but in your sheet they are in column G?

Comment: I correct a qustion and sheet, sorry for mess. I want a Arrayformula in column 'H' now

Comment: I'm not sure if `ARRAYFORMULA` works with `MEDIAN`.  As a test, I tried:  `=ARRAYFORMULA(MEDIAN(D3:D4,E3:E4))` and it only returns one value.

Comment: Adam, perhaps your question could be simplified, or re-asked - how do you create an arrayformula to calculate the median of three different values from one row.  If someone can help you do that, the rest of your formula should be fine, right?   `=ARRAYFORMULA(MEDIAN(A1:A,B1:B,C1:C))`  only returns one row for me...

Comment: Thank you, you are right. The "Arrayformula" have problems with "Median". Thanks for advice!